# displaying visual swtach images

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento-1.7

I created a visual swatch attribute from admin panel to adding 'brands' for products,In my Main/Store module i created brands.phtml file , and there is a Brands.php file inside Block folder, now problem is with getting image url or its name , i didnt know, i get the attribute values and the frontend label values , but i didnt how to get the images :( ,i searched on internet but i didnt get a useful answer, i tried many things but sometimes i get url image that contains pub/static/... url and as i know the path of images must be from media folder, can anyone help me with getting the full url of the images to display them , then i when user click on the image it will return the user to the products that under this brand , so i want to get url for each brand like this

```
<a href='link for all products that i chose this brand for them'><img src='image_source' /></a>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the URL or path of the images associated with the visual swatch attribute in Magento, you can use the following steps:

1. Retrieve the attribute options and their values in your block file **(Brands.php).** You can use the **Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface** and **Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data** classes for this purpose. Here's an example of how you can retrieve the attribute options:

```php
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data as SwatchHelper;

class Brands extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $attributeRepository;

    /**
     * @var SwatchHelper
     */
    private $swatchHelper;

    public function __construct(
        AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        SwatchHelper $swatchHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute options and their values
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getBrandOptions()
    {
        $attributeCode = 'brands'; // Replace with your attribute code
        $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $attributeCode);
        $options = $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId([$attribute->getId()]);

        $brandOptions = [];
        foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $option) {
            if (isset($options[$option->getValue()])) {
                $swatchData = $options[$option->getValue()];
                $brandOptions[] = [
                    'label' => $option->getLabel(),
                    'value' => $option->getValue(),
                    'swatch' => $swatchData['value'],
                    'swatchUrl' => $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchMediaUrl($swatchData['value'])
                ];
            }
        }

        return $brandOptions;
    }
}
```

2. In your **brands**.phtml template file, you can loop through the brand options and display the image URLs along with the brand labels. Here's an example:

```php
<?php foreach ($block->getBrandOptions() as $brand): ?>
    <a href="<?php /* Add your URL for the brand's products here */ ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($brand['swatchUrl']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($brand['label']); ?>">
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Make sure to replace **brands** with your actual attribute code, and customize the URL for each brand's products as needed.

**Note:** The example assumes that you have already set up the visual swatch attribute and associated the images with the attribute options through the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

bro it looks there is not getSwatchMediaUrl() function inside swatchHelper,
there is a function maybe it is the same i dont know
[image]

and this is other
[image]

now look here to getId it is also undefined method
[image]